# How to fix Flask Error 405 Method not allowed?

Tags: python, forms, flask, python-requests-html

Code:

I have two databases UnsortedReviews and SortedReviews. The first database stores all reviews received from users using the form (the page with this form works fine)
Reviews from this database are shown on a page /sort_review accessible only to the admin.
Using a form consisting of two buttons, he can either add a review to the database or not. The review from the database should be deleted in any case. Below is the code for the page /sort_review.

```
@app.route('/sort_review', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def sort_review():
    if 'adminLogged' not in session:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    global CURRENT_ID
    if request.method == "POST":
        if "reject" in request.form:
            UnsortedReview.query.filter_by(id=CURRENT_ID).delete()
            db.session.commit()
        elif "confirm" in request.form:
            r = UnsortedReview.query.filter_by(id=CURRENT_ID)
            review = r.review
            r.delete()
            db.session.commit()
            d = SortedReview(review=review)
            db.session.add(d)
            db.session.flush()
            db.session.commit()
    tmp = UnsortedReview.query.first()
    if tmp is None:
        return render_template('sort_review.html', flag=False, review='')
    else:
        CURRENT_ID = tmp.id
        return render_template('sort_review.html', flag=True, review=tmp.review)
```

Database structure

```
class SortedReview(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    review = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
```

sort_review.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="{{url_for('static', filename='css/style.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{url_for('static', filename='css/button.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>ArtHouse Hotel</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="all">
    <div class="back">
        <a id="back" href="/admin"><h2> Back </h2> </a>
    </div>
    {% if flag %}
    <form action="/sort-review" method="post">
        <div class="form">
            <div id="one-rev">
                <p> {{ review }} </p>
            </div>
            <div class="sort-review">
                <input type="submit" id="reject" name="reject" value="Reject">
                <input type="submit" id="confirm" name="confirm" value="Confirm">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    {% else %}
    <h2> No reviews left </h2>
    {% endif %}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Аfter clicking the form's submit button an error appears:

```
POST /sort-review HTTP/1.1" 200 -
reject=RejectGET /static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 405 -
```

I have no idea why get request becomes like this

Help me please )

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the page code, you wrote `/sort_review` and in sort_review.html you wrote `/sort-review`. I guess the mistake is in this.